# Triggering course completion in SCORM 1.2

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm1.2

I've got SCORM 1.2 saving and updating objectives correctly but I can't seem to trigger the actual course completion. When the course is loaded into our test Managed Learning Environment (MLE) we get the following behaviour:

When the last objective is completed, the course completion fires off, as expected.

The SCORM console.log-ing says the course completion has been recorded successfully.

When the user closes the course window, the course completion is in fact NOT registered with our MLE.

When the user returns to the course and completes any objective (which have all previously been completed) the course completion fires off again, as expected - but this time when they close the course window, the course completion HAS registered with our MLE.

So, is there something about the exit characteristics that I should be including?

Here's how we set up an objective:

```
vault.SCORM.set('cmi.objectives.'+numberOfObjectives+'.id', tempComponentString);
vault.SCORM.save();
vault.SCORM.set('cmi.objectives.'+numberOfObjectives+'.status', 'incomplete');
vault.SCORM.save();
```

Here's how the objectives get completed:

```
vault.SCORM.set("cmi.objectives." + pages[pageId-1].componentSCORMIndexesById[element.componentId()] + ".status" , "completed");
vault.SCORM.save();
```

Those are all working fine. It's the course completion that's the problem. Here's the code for that:

```
vault.SCORM.set("cmi.core.lesson_status" , "completed");
vault.SCORM.save();
```

Just to repeat: This course completion console.logs as if it has fired off correctly the first time the course is actually completed, but the course is only registered as complete with our MLE when the user returns to the course and clicks a completed component (which triggers an objective completion and the above course completion again).

Is there something about how we've set up the objectives that would be preventing actual completion the first time? Or is it to do with exit characteristics / suspend data?

If anyone has any pointers, that would be great!

**EDIT**

I've done some more testing and temporarily taken OUT the calls to set 'cmi.objectives'. The course completion now works correctly. So it's something about the presence of the objectives that's preventing the course completing correctly. Is there some extra property that needs to be set to really complete an objective?

Comment: One thing you could check via  https://www.cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM/ is to view the objective data to see that all objectives are truly satisfied.  I've seen some LMS systems have a phantom objective.  I don't know where it comes from but it may be something they internally do for one reason or another.  Both interactions and objectives can dropdown in this bookmarklet to give you a view of the current status.  Hit refresh as needed.

Comment: It turns out it was all the 'save's that were throwing things out. We reduced it down to just the one save and it seems like SCORM now has the time to register all the changes.

Comment: ok so a lot of commits spamming the LMS.  Some platforms use a synchronous communication model on those which can lead to performance issues.  Good job tracking it down.